# How can I use conditional statement in style jsx with Next.js?

Tags: css, next.js, styled-jsx

I am using `<style jsx>` in Next.js and would like to style an element with conditional statement.
I am also using tailwindCSS:

```html
<div
className="mt-20 description_content text-center flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-gray-500 mx-5"
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
__html: productDetail?.description,}}>
</div>
```

```css
        .description_content p:first-child {
          position: relative !important;
          overflow: hidden !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          padding-top: 56.25% !important; /* if there is no iframe tag as a child, it should be padding-top: 0px; */
        }

        .description_content p iframe {
          position: absolute !important;
          top: 0 !important;
          left: 0 !important;
          bottom: 0 !important;
          right: 0 !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          height: 100% !important;
          margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
```

I would like to set up padding-top: 56.25% if there is a iframe tag under first p tag, however, if there's no iframe tag under first p tag, I would like to set up padding-top: 0px;

Is there a way to use conditional statement in css?

Comment: Did you try with if-else? create two rules and pass on elements with if else.

Comment: See the simple example.
`<img src={this.state.photo} alt="" style={ isLoggedIn ? { display:'block'} : {display : 'none'} } />`

Comment: The problem is I am using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, so I cannot physically approach to the tag, that's why I used style tag below.

Comment: create one more class, set padding, and try to pass that class with the if-else statement I hope you understand. No need to target the element

Answer (score 0):

As per [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/blog/styling-next-with-styled-jsx), what you can do is add the style jsx tag and do it as in this example:

```
<div
className="mt-20 description_content text-center flex flex-col justify-center items-center text-gray-500 mx-5"
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
__html: productDetail?.description,}}>
<style jsx>{`
 .description_content p:first-child {
   padding-top: ${yourConditionHere ? '56.25%' : '0'};
  }
`}</style>
</div>
```

Change yourConditionHere for the iframe condition in the code.